# How do I keep the leaves on my Fukien tea bonsai from turning brown and/or falling off?

Tags: bonsai

[image]

This is what my poor little bonsai looks like. What can I do??

Comment: Bit more info please  - how long have you had the plant? Where have you kept it, indoors or outside, in sun or not? And is there anything under the leaves -  the deposits on top might indicate an insect infestation. check with a magnifying glass, because the image doesn't magnify well.

Comment: A co-worker has taken the plant home to try to nurse it back to health. Thanks for your response!!